# Card stack animation

Tags: android, android-animation

In my activity, I have two card views, one for sign in and one for signup.
They are in a stack. When I click on any of the cards it should animate like this,
https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/82e47d53917017.5971cd622e847.gif

I am using Stack animation to achieve this but it is not working properly.
So can anyone help me out in achieving this,

```
 stackAnimation.animateStacks(cardViewSignUp, cardViewSignIn, AppConstants.ANIMATION_END_SCALE);
```

This is my StackAnimation Class,

```
public class StackAnimation {
private int duration;
private float startScale;
private float pivot;

public StackAnimation(int duration, float startScale, float pivot) {
    this.duration = duration;
    this.startScale = startScale;
    this.pivot = pivot;
}

public void animateStacks(CardView cardViewFront, CardView cardViewBack,
                          float endScale) {
    cardViewBack.bringToFront();
    scaleView(cardViewBack, startScale, endScale, startScale, endScale);
    scaleView(cardViewFront, startScale, startScale - (endScale - startScale), startScale, startScale - (endScale - startScale));
}

private void scaleView(View view, float startScaleY, float endScaleY, float startScaleX,
                       float endScaleX) {
    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            startScaleX, endScaleX, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            startScaleY, endScaleY, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, pivot, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, pivot); // Pivot point of Y scaling
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    anim.setDuration(duration);
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom library for it?

Comment: no i am doing on ma own

Comment: is `stackAnimation` is inbuilt class ? If not then you should add more info abot the `stackAnimation` . Provide code .

Comment: i have added my stack animation class please check